# How to add "OnClick" event, to button from code-behind?

Tags: asp.net, button, onclick, code-behind

I've got this button (called "Accept") written in an action

```
 protected TableRow AddLineToNotificationsPanel(string type,int UserCode)
 {
      TableRow NotificationTR = new TableRow();
      TableCell AcceptTC = new TableCell();
      Button Accept = new Button();
      NotificationTR.Cells.Add(AcceptTC);
      AcceptTC.Controls.Add(Accept);

      Accept.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "check1");
            
        return NotificationTR;
  }
```

And this is the action "check1" (only built in order to check if the click is working).

```
    protected void check1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "TEXT CHANGED !";
    }
```

Upon clicking on the button, the text on Label1 is not changed.

Any ideas why would it not work ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the event to this button. You can do it like that:
`Accept.Click += new EventHandler(check1);`

Comment: Works great ! Thanks !